# twitter api returning too few tweets

Tags: php, twitter

I am trying to produce a PHP class for interactions with the twitter api (I realise there are some in the wild, but I like to do things my way). The problem I have is the number of tweets returned is one less than expected after 2. So if I ask for one, I get one; if I ask for two, I get two; if I ask for three, I get two; if I ask for four, I get three; five produced four and so. I have tested up to eleven.

Here is the query code:

```
$callback = new SimpleXMLElement($this->api_method, NULL, TRUE);
```

and this is what is returned if I log `$this->api_method`:

```
http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.xml?screen_name=mildfuzz&count=3
```

Count number behaves as expected throughout.

Comment: "I realise there are some in the wild, but I like to do things my way." http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_Invented_Here

Comment: bah, I dispute this. I am not a senior coder, so I do it all for experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because some of the tweets are being ignored as they aren't important enough to be included in the indexing process.

[Twitter competition ~ saving tweets (PHP & MySQL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442116/twitter-competition-saving-tweets-php-mysql) Is the question that I had concerning this. It turns out that at least with the **search api** they will not return all the tweets as some are not good enough to be indexed. So this might be why you are missing some out.

I would link the Twitter docs here with the article about the Twitter search api restrictions, but Twitter has since been banned at my work, sorry. Have a google for it :)